# How to accept invalid certificate of SSL connection automatically using .net in C++?

Tags: .net, c++, ssl

I am using VC 2008 and using .net codes. The HttpWebRequest client I made can never connect to server which is using an untrusted certificate (I crafted that cert, so it is untrusted). The error is "TrustFailure".

In C#, we can do

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

But how to convert that into C++ syntax?

```
ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
// does not work
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I have defined a delegate method in my class and registered it in the constructor for 
System::Net::ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback

```
bool CMyClass::AcceptingCertificate(System::Object^ rObjectSender, X509Certificate^ rX509Certificate, X509Chain^ rX509Chain , SslPolicyErrors rErrors)
{
  return true;
}

CMyClass::CMyClass(void)
{
  System::Net::ServicePointManager::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = gcnew RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(&CMyClass::AcceptingCertificate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but can't you write c# method that handles this and just call that from your C++ code?